# How do I change the output file in VSCode?

Tags: python, file, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

In VSCode, while running python, every time I go to print something, I am met with an error. I can see that I am running a virtualenv that I have deleted and can not for the life of me figure out how to change the output. I am sure it is a simple solution, **but how does one stop running VSCode output in an old and deleted file, and begin running new code in a working file/directory?** I have cycled through every interpreter and run "print("...")" with the same result. I have deleted all virtual environments using "sudo rm -rf venv" and still receive the same error - that there is a missing file or directory. images provided below:

VSCode is [Running] a file I have deleted in Output -
[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQGMI.png)

/bin/sh: file or directory not found
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFfkp.png)

I tried deleting all virtual environments, running the code in every available interpreter and searching every variation of this question to no avail.

Comment: why are there `<>` in the filenames, use the `venv` module as shown in Python VSC tutorial

Comment: hi @rioV8 - thank you for your comment. <> was added to the folder named "<> Languages" on my desktop.

Comment: ever wondered why that is not a good idea? Ever heard of file redirection in the terminal/shell

Comment: @rioV8 - thank you for asking. I have never heard of file redirection in the shell or that adding "<>" to a file was a bad idea. I would like to know how to adjust. I have deleted the file before getting the error message. Any way this can be undone?

Comment: then it is a good idea to do a google search for `file redirection`, it is the same reason you should not put `*&?[]` in your filenames

Comment: @rioV8 you have been most helpful. thank you so much. As a result of my ignorance, and to solve the problem, I backed up all files (after excluding the symbols mentioned) and restored my system to factory settings. It seemed to be the only way and worked perfectly. Thank you for taking the time to educate me on file redirection

Comment: also `;:` are better not used for filenames, maybe some other, stick to `[-a-zA-Z0-9_]` and the locale word characters

Answer (score 1):

Inside of VSCode extension "Code Runner" the settings.JSON file needed to be debugged. The initial curly braces were removed through some operation - and the output for python was:
"python": "python -u";
it needed to be changed to:
"python": "python3";
however the settings changes couldn't be implemented when changing the python output as the entire settings string was missing the first "{" braces - by deleting the entire settings list and leaving "{ }" the settings were reset, Code Runner extension was uninstalled automatically and upon installation, all settings were reloaded correctly (containing the initial curly braces that were missing) Then I was able to change:
"python -u" to "python3" and the output finally showed the commands.

Literal weeks to discover this answer and I tried everything.